# Reading column delimited text data in python quickly

Tags: python, numpy, fortran

I have a column delimited data in a text file containing many variables. The original file was created in Fortran. The number of values in each row is fixed (i.e 8). For example a value "-0.213897E-05" is immediately by seven other values on the same line. A blank column means "+ve sign". There are 8 such rows but the total number of values could be between 62 and 64.
Then there are about 1000 such variables.

An example of the one variable in the file is as follows.

```
     -0.213897E-05 0.106493E-06-0.530198E-08 0.263970E-09-0.131423E-10 0.654316E-12-0.325765E-13 0.162189E-14
     -0.427794E-05 0.212986E-06-0.106040E-07 0.527940E-09-0.262846E-10 0.130863E-11-0.651530E-13 0.324377E-14
     -0.641691E-05 0.319479E-06-0.159059E-07 0.791910E-09-0.394269E-10 0.196295E-11-0.977294E-13 0.486566E-14
     -0.855588E-05 0.425972E-06-0.212079E-07 0.105588E-08-0.525692E-10 0.261726E-11-0.130306E-12 0.648755E-14
     -0.106949E-04 0.532465E-06-0.265099E-07 0.131985E-08-0.657114E-10 0.327158E-11-0.162882E-12 0.810944E-14
     -0.128338E-04 0.638958E-06-0.318119E-07 0.158382E-08-0.788537E-10 0.392590E-11-0.195459E-12 0.973132E-14
     -0.149728E-04 0.745452E-06-0.371138E-07 0.184779E-08-0.919960E-10 0.458021E-11-0.228035E-12 0.113532E-13
     -0.171118E-04 0.851945E-06-0.424158E-07 0.211176E-08-0.105138E-09
```

I have successfully read the file using readlines() and then converting the string into floats but the result is slow and time-consuming. I also tried FortranFormat which was even slower. The total size of the file is about 2GB.

Please suggest a native way to read these values. I have about 1000 such variables in the file.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you'd use regex for.

Comment: @EdwardL. I doubt regex would be the most performant approach, given that the data structure is known.

Comment: @EdwardL. U mean i should read values as string and the use regex on a string? won't that be as slow as using readlines like I am doing? I want to read them as floats natively not as strings.

Comment: If that's the format of the file when you open it as text file, it's written as text strings, not natively... "Natively" would mean it's written in binary and you wouldn't even be able to open it in a text editor. In other words, it wouldn't be human-readable.

Comment: *How* were you *"converting the string into floats"*? Could you show a code sample to set a performance baseline?

Comment: @EdwardL. No I mean they are floats. In FORTRAN I have a format statement (like other compiled languages) that can read and write float values to a text file. I want to read the floats natively not read it as a string as is usually done. The file is long and I am left to twiddle my fingers when all variables have been read. My colleagues who use FORTRAN make fun of python.

Comment: @CorruptedStack you can't do that, Python will read in the file as a string. However, you should look into `numpy`, which may offer a lower-level access to FORTRAN files.

Comment: @AirThomas A large code written in fortran writes them. I can't go back and forth between fortran and python while the "unit" (or file handle) is open in fortran.

Comment: Perhaps [IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages#Fortran) from the Python wiki is useful?

Comment: @AirThomas Cant have a file left open in fortran inside a python loop. It will read the file again from the start right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas can help here, there's [a section about reading fixed width files in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#files-with-fixed-width-columns), reading the text as StringIO (a file would work just the same).

```
In [21]: colspecs = [(5 + 13 * i, 5 + 13 * (i + 1)) for i in range(8)]

In [22]: pd.read_fwf(StringIO(s), colspecs=colspecs, header=None)
Out[22]:
          0         1             2             3             4             5             6             7
0 -0.000002  0.000000 -5.301980e-09  2.639700e-10 -1.314230e-11  6.543160e-13 -3.257650e-14  1.621890e-15
1 -0.000004  0.000000 -1.060400e-08  5.279400e-10 -2.628460e-11  1.308630e-12 -6.515300e-14  3.243770e-15
2 -0.000006  0.000000 -1.590590e-08  7.919100e-10 -3.942690e-11  1.962950e-12 -9.772940e-14  4.865660e-15
3 -0.000009  0.000000 -2.120790e-08  1.055880e-09 -5.256920e-11  2.617260e-12 -1.303060e-13  6.487550e-15
4 -0.000011  0.000001 -2.650990e-08  1.319850e-09 -6.571140e-11  3.271580e-12 -1.628820e-13  8.109440e-15
5 -0.000013  0.000001 -3.181190e-08  1.583820e-09 -7.885370e-11  3.925900e-12 -1.954590e-13  9.731320e-15
6 -0.000015  0.000001 -3.711380e-08  1.847790e-09 -9.199600e-11  4.580210e-12 -2.280350e-13  1.135320e-14
7 -0.000017  0.000001 -4.241580e-08  2.111760e-09 -1.051380e-10           NaN           NaN           NaN
```

*These have been read in as floats*.

---

Original answer: [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files) might help you here, it's great for delimited text files:

```
pd.read_csv('your_file.txt', sep=' ')
```

Comment: The OP's example doesn't have delimiters, it's fixed-width.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's space delimited?

Comment: No, the space is only for positive values; negative values continue straight on.

Comment: As @jonrsharpe says its fixed-width not delimited.

Comment: @AndyHayden Thank you! Your answer worked for me.. I thought of waiting for more answers but I guess, this works for now :)